# OSStatus-Error when trying to tell Time Machine to use external server as backup drive

Tags: macos, samba, raspberry-pi, time-machine, smb

I want to use a Raspberry Pi 3 as a backup drive for my Mac using Time Machine. Therefore I

1. installed Samba 4.8.0 which shall be able to be connected to by the Time Machine backup software according to their [bug tracker](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12380#c22).
2. activated the Samba service via `sudo systemctl enable smbd`. The output of `sudo systemctl status smbd` states `Active: active (running)`.
3. tried many example configurations for `/etc/samba/smbd.config` namely [this](http://wa.rwick.com/2018/04/08/minimal-ubuntu-time-machine-backup-service/), [this](https://kirb.me/2018/03/24/using-samba-as-a-time-machine-network-server.html), [this](https://gist.github.com/ChloeTigre/4c2022c0d1a281deedba6f7539a2e3ae), [this](https://gist.github.com/ChloeTigre/4c2022c0d1a281deedba6f7539a2e3ae#gistcomment-2403488) and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/83vkaz/howto_make_time_machine_backups_on_a_samba/).

When trying to connect Time Machine to the Samba share there is always this one error message after successfully providing my login details:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3xGQ.png)

It translates to:

> Time Machine can not connect to the backup volume.
>
> The operation could not be completed. (OSStatus error -1073741275.)

The OSStatus error is unknown to https://www.osstatus.com/ and honestly seems more like a buggy overflow than a valid error code. (It's almost -2^30.)

What could be the cause of this error and how can I fix it?

I'm using:

- macOS 10.13.5
- Linux raspberrypi 4.9.35-v7+
- Samba 4.8.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to turn on samba logging to see detail error.
For me, this error means my avahi advertised name is different from my samba share name.
in smb.conf

```
## Definde your shares here
[TimeMachine Home]
```

And in avahi service definition:

```
 <service>
   <type>_adisk._tcp</type>
   <txt-record>sys=waMa=0,adVF=0x100</txt-record>
   <txt-record>dk0=adVN=TimeMachine Home,adVF=0x82</txt-record>
 </service>
```

The "TimeMachine Home" string in above config.

Config reference:
https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/83vkaz/howto_make_time_machine_backups_on_a_samba/

Answer (score 3):

Check Samba logs in /var/log/samba/log.*[your client's hostname]*.

In my case, the log said:

> Error loading module '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/vfs/streams_xattr.so': /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/vfs/streams_xattr.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

For some reason, the VFS module "streams_xattr", which is needed for Time Machine to operate properly, was missing.

I fixed it by installing a package for VFS modules:

```
sudo apt install samba-vfs-modules
```

Then I restarted samba:

```
sudo systemctl restart smbd
```

And I was able to authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that Googled for `OSStatus error -1073741275` and ended up here:

Are you trying to *reconnect* your Time Machine to your NAS, and was it working just fine before?

(And maybe, are you using a pre-built NAS, like a Synology or Netgear, and don't have easy access to the samba logging settings like @hnws suggests?)

Then please make sure that you are using the exact same username / account on your NAS that you have previously used to connect Time Machine to your NAS, and make sure that the account still has (the same) permissions for the Time Machine share.

Comment: Lol sometimes it's the simplest thing! Thanks for your answer.